# Using a charged capacitor to charge two others

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Here is the homework question in question: 
The figure (below) displays a 13.1 V battery and three uncharged capacitors of capacitances C1 = 4.08 μF,C2 = 6.19 μF and C3 = 3.30 μF. The switch is thrown to the left side until capacitor 1 is fully charged. Then the switch is thrown to the right. What is the final charge (in C) on capacitor 3?

[image: Diagram]

Here is what I did: I first found the final charge on C1 before flipping the switch right, by doing Q=CV and I got 53.488 microcoulombs. Easy

Then I assumed that after the switch is flipped, 2q coulombs of charge have flowed out of the top plate of C1, and that you end up with a charge q+a on C2 and q-a on C3, so that total charge is conserved where q and a are unknown charges. Since at the end the potential of C2 and C3 must be equal, I wrote

$\frac{q+a}{6.19}=\frac{q-a}{3.3}=V=Q/C$

I solved for a and found that a=.3045q, so that C2 will attain a charge of 1.3045q and C3 will attain a charge of .6955q.

To find q, I did the same thing but with C1 and C2: 
$\frac{1.3045q}{6.19}=\frac{53.488-2q}{4.08}$ and found that q=18.7 microcoulombs, and then some arithmetic gave me the answer: C1 has a charge of 16.08 microcoulombs, C2 24.39 microcoulombs, and C3 13 microcoulombs. However, my Wiley says its wrong. Confirm that the voltage difference across all of the capacitors is 3.94 V. 
What's wrong about my process?

Comment: You didn't tell us what is $q$ and what is $a$.

Comment: 2q represents the charge that flows out of C1 and q+a represents the charge accumulated by C2, and q-a that of C3. a represents how the 2q coulombs of charge is distributed between C2 and C3

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong about my process?

You're answer cannot be correct since it does not satisfy KVL.

For your final charge solution, the final voltages across the capacitors are given by

$$V_{C1} = \frac{16.08}{4.08}\mathrm V =  3.94\mathrm V $$

$$V_{C2} = \frac{24.39}{6.19}\mathrm V =  3.94\mathrm V $$

$$V_{C3} = \frac{13}{3.3}\mathrm V =  3.94\mathrm V $$

But, by KVL, the voltages *must* satisfy

$$V_{C1} =  V_{C2} + V_{C3}$$

so, back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1):

We are forbidden to solve home-works, but we are allowed to help.

So, I can remind you that you know the formula for the total capacitance of $C_2$ and $C_3$ together.

Also, since after the charges are re-distributed, the potential difference $V$ between the upper plate of $C_2$ and lower plate of $C_3$, is the same as between the plates of $C_1$.

As you also know the total charge, you are supposed to get two relations between the quantities $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $V$, where I denoted by $Q_2$ the charge on the upper plate of $Q_2$. I believe that this can help.

Comment: That was my second thought but here is what didn't make sense to me: this means that C2 and C3 have different voltages, so why wouldn't more charge flow from one to the other? Why does it just stop?

Comment: @FarazMasroor To answer you, means to solve the problem for you, and as I said, we are forbidden. You first find the charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, and the answer to your comment we will find together. I repeat, do you know the formula that gives you the equivalent capacitance $C$ of two capacitors connected in series? Then please, find $C$, then find $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, s.t. we can progress with your problem.

Comment: I do but I don't understand why my solution was wrong. Wouldn't the difference in charge between C2 and C3 cause charge to flow?

Comment: @FarazMasroor How can be a difference in charge between $C2$ and $C3$? The amount of positive charge that passes from the upper plate of $C_1$ to the upper plate of $C_2$, is equal but opposite in sign to the amount of charge that passes from the lower plate of $C_1$ to the lower plate of $C_3$. And next, the positive charge that will appear on the upper plate on $C_3$ is taken from the lower plate of $C_2$. So, why should there be different charges on $C_2$ and $C_3$? The capacitances are different s.t. the potential fall on them is different, but why should the charges differ?

Comment: Sorry meant differences in voltages. Don't charged particles travel places because of different voltages?

Comment: @FarazMasroor A positive charge $Q_2$ passes from the positive plate of $C_1$ to the positive plate of $C_2$, and $-Q_2$ passes from the negative plate of $C_1$ to the negative plate of $C_3$. Since the plates of a capacitor are equally charged but of opposite sign, from the lower plate of $C_2$, a positive charge $Q_2$ will migrate to the upper plate of $C_3$. Thus, if you find $Q_2$ you'll be able in continuation to find the fall of potential on each one from $C_2$ and $C_3$.